# How to change Javascript carousel (slick.js) settings on one page only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I'm using [Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) by Ken Wheeler. I set the global settings (for the whole site) to autoplay slides like this:

```
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 5000,
```

but on **one** page on the site I don't want it to autoplay.
Is there any way I can override this global setting using an inline script?

Something like this:

```
<script>
function (iSuckAtJavaScript) {
autoplay: false,
};
</script>
```

?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could approach it depending on how your site is set up and how the plugin gets initialized. But to fill in the `iSuckAtJavaScript` part of your question, you could match on a specific path/page like this.

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/no-autoplay-page.html') {
  // Initialize the carousel
}
```

Comment: Thank you, since the website is dynamic, how do I make it so that it works for everything in a parent folder, for example everything under '/pages/...' 

Also, what is the correct way to add this to the slick.js document?
here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/0abtukmh/

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code you're using to initialize the plugin and what file it's in? Also the general structure of the site/files?